# Gaming Function in Arduino

Tags: loops, for-loop, while-loop, arduino, do-while

I'm trying to make a Whack-A-Mole game using an Arduino Mega with 10 LEDs (Moles) and 10 Push Buttons (Whack). The electronics are completed and tested, everything works fine. It also has a BLE radio attached which prompts the board to start one of three games I plan to do.

The problem I'm having is this:

In my main loop, I listen for a command from the app coming via BLE. When a "1" is sent by the app (serial pass through), I call the function

playGameOne();

The main thing is that everything loops in the main loop fine, but when I jump to the game function, it runs once and returns back to the main loop again. How can I keep the user looping in the game function until the game is over? Oh - and I'm not trying to use any Interrupts, but I imagine thats one way of doing it.

The latest incarnation of the game function looks like this:

```
    //////////////////////////////////////////////
//////////////////  GAME 1  //////////////////


void gameOne(){


  //var int eTime;



  // inform player game is about to begin
  playCountdown();
  Serial.println("Game Begun");

  // initialize var to count time
  elapsedMillis timeElapsed;

  if(gameState < 1){

  gameOneOne();

      Serial.print("Game finished - Your time: ");
      Serial.println(timeElapsed);
  }
}




void gameOneOne(){
  while(digitalRead(btPin31) == LOW){

    // turn on LED45

    digitalWrite(ledPin45, HIGH);
    // wait for user to push corresponding button
    if(digitalRead(btPin31) == HIGH){
      // turn off the LED and jump to next LED - gameOneTwo()
      digitalWrite(ledPin45, LOW);

      gameOneTwo();

    }

  }  
}



void gameOneTwo(){
    while(digitalRead(btPin39) == LOW){

    // turn on LED53

    digitalWrite(ledPin53, HIGH);

    if(digitalRead(btPin39) == HIGH){
      digitalWrite(ledPin53, LOW);

      // Finish the game, set state to 1
      gameState = 1;

    }

  } 
}
```

Not only this doesn't work, I highly doubt this is the proper way of coding games. In fact the ideal would be to have a Game Script that can be uploaded dynamically. The game Script would look like:

```
Header {name of game}
45 {pin of first LED}
500 {how long to keep it on, in ms}
49 {pin of the second LED}
500 {how long to keep it on, in ms}
... and so on
End of File
```

What is the best resource to learn this properly.

EDIT

Here's my main loop

```
// included header files
#include <elapsedMillis.h>    // Measuring Elapsed Time Library


// Constant - Piezzo Speaker Pin
const int beepPin = 11;       // the number of the Piezo Spkr pin

// Constants - Button Pins
const int btPin30 = 30;
const int btPin31 = 31;
const int btPin32 = 32;
const int btPin33 = 33;
const int btPin34 = 34;
const int btPin35 = 35;
const int btPin36 = 36;
const int btPin37 = 37;
const int btPin38 = 38;
const int btPin39 = 39;

// Constants - LED Pins
const int ledPin53 = 53;
const int ledPin52 = 52;
const int ledPin51 = 51;
const int ledPin50 = 50;
const int ledPin49 = 49;
const int ledPin48 = 48;
const int ledPin47 = 47;
const int ledPin46 = 46;
const int ledPin45 = 45;
const int ledPin44 = 44;

//Variable for storing BLUETOOTH received data
char data = 0;             


// variables will change:
int buttonState = 0;         // variable for reading the pushbutton status

int btPin30State = 0;
int btPin31State = 0;
int btPin32State = 0;
int btPin33State = 0;
int btPin34State = 0;
int btPin35State = 0;
int btPin36State = 0;
int btPin37State = 0;
int btPin38State = 0;
int btPin39State = 0;


// declare game state variable
int gameState = 0;



void setup() {

  // initialize Serial Comms for Debug (0) and BT(3) 
  Serial.begin(9600);     //Sets the buad for Serial (debug port)
  Serial3.begin(9600);   //Sets the baud for Serial3 data transmission                               

  // initialize all button pins as INPUTs
  for (int x = 30; x <= 39; x++){
    pinMode(x, INPUT);
  }

  // initialize LED pins as OUTPUTs:
  for (int i = 44; i <= 53; i++){
    pinMode(i, OUTPUT);
  }

  // lightup all LEDs
  for (int j = 44; j <= 53; j++){
    digitalWrite(j, HIGH);
    delay(100);
  }

  // prompt device is ready
  Serial.println("Device Ready");

}








void loop() {

  // Read Data from Serial3 -- This is to get initial game status/command from app/bluetooth
   if(Serial3.available() > 0)   {   // Send data only when you receive data:

    data = Serial3.read();



    // See what the command is
    if(data == '1') {
      Serial.write("Send it to GameOne");
      Serial.write("\n");
      gameOne();
    }

    // See what the command is
    if(data == '2') {
      Serial.write("Send it to GameTwo");
      Serial.write("\n");
      gameTwo();
    }

    if(data == '3') {
      Serial.write("Send it to GameThree");
      Serial.write("\n");
      gameThree();
    }

    if(data == '4') {
      Serial.write("Test");
      Serial.write("\n");
    }


   }



btPin30State = digitalRead(btPin30);
btPin31State = digitalRead(btPin31);
btPin32State = digitalRead(btPin32);
btPin33State = digitalRead(btPin33);
btPin34State = digitalRead(btPin34);
btPin35State = digitalRead(btPin35);
btPin36State = digitalRead(btPin36);
btPin37State = digitalRead(btPin37);
btPin38State = digitalRead(btPin38);
btPin39State = digitalRead(btPin39);


// check if the pushbutton is pressed. If it is, the buttonState is HIGH:


if (btPin30State == HIGH) {
  digitalWrite(ledPin44, HIGH);
  tone(11, 1000, 500);
  Serial.println("BTN 30 / LED 44");
  gameOne();
} else {
  digitalWrite(ledPin44, LOW);
}

if (btPin31State == HIGH) {
  digitalWrite(ledPin45, HIGH);
  Serial.println("BTN 31 / LED 45");
} else {
  digitalWrite(ledPin45, LOW);
}

if (btPin32State == HIGH) {
  digitalWrite(ledPin46, HIGH);
  Serial.println("BTN 32 / LED 46");
} else {
  digitalWrite(ledPin46, LOW);
} 

if (btPin33State == HIGH) {
  digitalWrite(ledPin47, HIGH);
  Serial.println("BTN 33 / LED 47");
} else {
  digitalWrite(ledPin47, LOW);
}

if (btPin34State == HIGH) {
  digitalWrite(ledPin48, HIGH);
  Serial.println("BTN 34 / LED 48");
} else {
  digitalWrite(ledPin48, LOW);
}

if (btPin35State == HIGH) {
  digitalWrite(ledPin49, HIGH);
  Serial.println("BTN 35 / LED 49");
} else {
  digitalWrite(ledPin49, LOW);
}

if (btPin36State == HIGH) {
  digitalWrite(ledPin50, HIGH);
  Serial.println("BTN 36 / LED 50");
} else {
  digitalWrite(ledPin50, LOW);
}

if (btPin37State == HIGH) {
  digitalWrite(ledPin51, HIGH);
  Serial.println("BTN 37 / LED 51");
} else {
  digitalWrite(ledPin51, LOW);
}

if (btPin38State == HIGH) {
  digitalWrite(ledPin52, HIGH);
  Serial.println("BTN 38 / LED 52");
} else {
  digitalWrite(ledPin52, LOW);
}

if (btPin39State == HIGH) {
  digitalWrite(ledPin53, HIGH);
  Serial.println("BTN 39 / LED 53");
} else {
  digitalWrite(ledPin53, LOW);
}




}
```

Comment: You should post your main as well.

Comment: Done. See the main post pls

Comment: You should consider reducing your code size, by the use of arrays and for loops.

Comment: Having looked at it a bit, I think your issue is related to the fact that gameState gets changed from 0 to 1 and never gets changed back.  I suggest making a smaller sketch that deals with one or two moles and work from there.  the only real way to debug is with a bunch of print statements.

Comment: Yes, I'm working on a smaller/cleaner version. But the crux of the issue, irrespective of this, is my fundamental understanding of what happens when you jump to a function outside of the main loop. Once game() runs, it returns to Main. How do I STAY IN game() until I change my state (eg game ends)?

Comment: It's not clear what your gameoneOne and gameOneTwo are supposed to be doing. But if you want your function to run until a state variable changes, Why don't you put the function body inside a while loop that checks for the state?

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be ok to structure it something like this.

```
play_a_game:
    for (some_number_of_times)
    {
        show_a_mole_and_let_them_wackit();
    }

setup:
    set up pins
    say the game is starting

loop:
    do
    {
        play_a_game();
    }
    while(game ending button not pressed and less then 10 moles have died);

    say the game is over
```

Comment: I have something very similar to this now. However, when the button is pressed (goes high) the condition of the do/while doesn't change. I am NOT using an interrupt... but from all my reading, I shouldn't have to in Arduino. Any insight?